# Encode URL with US-ASCII character set

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, ascii, url-encoding

I refer to the following web site:

http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii

Choosing "URL", "Encode", and "US-ASCII", the input is converted to the desired output.

How do I produce the same output with Java codes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this and it seems to work fine.

```
public static String encode(String input) {
    Pattern doNotReplace = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
    
    return input.chars().mapToObj(c->{
        if(!doNotReplace.matcher(String.valueOf((char)c)).matches()){
            return "%" + (c<256?Integer.toHexString(c):"u"+Integer.toHexString(c));
        }
        return String.valueOf((char)c);
    }).collect(Collectors.joining("")).toUpperCase();
}
```

---

*PS: I'm using 256 to limit the placement of the prefix U to non-ASCII characters. No need of prefix U for standard ASCII characters which are within 256.*

---

> Alternate option:

There is a built-in Java class (`java.net.URLEncoder`) that does URL Encoding. But it works a little differently (For example, it does not replace the Space character   with `%20`, but replaces with a `+` instead. Something similar happens with other characters too). [See if it helps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(input, "US-ASCII");
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, both options seem to work. Why does the second option work "a little differently". It seems to produce the same result as first option.

Comment: The web site's output is not exactly correct. It should encode the / character, but it didn't.

Comment: The second one works differently. For example, it does not replace space with `%20`, but replaces with a `+` instead. Something similar happens with other characters also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ESAPi.encoder().encodeForUrl(linkString)`

Check more details on encodeForUrl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

please comment if that does not satisfy your requirement or face any other issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, where is ESAPI from? It doesn't look like it is part of the standard JDK.